# Jackson not working for complex String?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've following as a String in Java. How to get only `{"FirstName":"Deepak","LastName":"Kabra"}` value from below String using Java or Jackson? Please help

```
{"map_":{"FirstName":"Deepak","LastName":"Kabra"}}"
```

Comment: Is this JSON object here already a JSON object or just a string?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend utilizing Jackson's TreeModel. If you use it and get the String into a JsonNode, then you can just use

jsonNode.get("map_")

and you'll have the string you want.

Edited with code example:

```
String jsonString = "{"map_":{"FirstName":"Deepak","LastName":"Kabra"}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode obj = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode desiredString = actualObj.get("map_");
```

Comment: Could you please share code snippet ?